# How do I get a radial gradient like this in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a radial gradient in a design that looks like this: [image]

It's extremely subtle, but in Figma, the CSS looks something like this:

[image]

The CSS according to figma:

```css
background: radial-gradient(50% 50% at 50% 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.116) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%), #15636D;
```

I tried something like this but it ended up looking way, way off:

```dart
gradient: RadialGradient(
      colors: [
        Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.116),
        Color.fromRGBO(152, 70, 242, 0),
        AppColors.primary, // #15636D
      ],
    ),
```

[image]

Is there a way to adjust the spread of this?

My backup plan is to just turn it into a background image if all else fails.

Comment: Can you share the figma file , i might be able to help you out

Comment: It's making your gradient transparent in the middle due to the opacity of the first two colors. The white is mostly from the background behind the widget, Try using [alphaBlend](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/alphaBlend.html) on the first two colors, ie `Color.alphaBlend(Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.116), AppColors.primary)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code

```dart
Container(
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    gradient: RadialGradient(
      colors: [
        Color(0xff366570),
        Color(0xff275662),
      ],
      center: Alignment.center,
      radius: 0.8,
    ),
  ),
)
```

It was generated with [gradient generagor](https://fluttergradientgenerator.com)